# I’m an electrical idiot - can you help me?

Tags: led, wiring, series, light

I have overhead doors at the back of my office building. I wanted to wire up a large red LED next to the light switch so that when employees leave, the light would be red indicating the doors are up.

I purchased a step down transformer of some sort that reduces the voltage to 6 V and powers the LED light. Magnetic switches are wired in series with the light to the step down transformer. (Hopefully all of that makes sense)

The light comes on so I have it wired correctly and nothing has caught on fire.

My issue is that the light is on when the doors are closed and the circuit is complete. I need to figure out how to wire or what to purchase so that the light comes on when the circuit is broken (the magnetic overhead door switch is open)?

Can anyone tell me what to do? I’ve tried Google and just can’t find what I’m looking for. Thanks in advance for any help!!! Also in advance, I don’t understand any diagrams for electronics. If you can help me, you’ll have to explain it like I’m an idiot.

Comment: Add some detail about switch that detects opened/closed door

Comment: Can you provide part numbers of the LED light, and the magnetic switches

Comment: First step: Write a title that describes the problem, instead of insulting yourself, which helps nobody.

Comment: Reed switches come in both normally open and normally closed sorts; you need the opposite of the one you currently have.

Comment: "Door is not closed" is not the same as "Door is open".

Comment: do you have an alarm system in your office?

Comment: If the door is not closed then it is open to some degree, not necessarily fully open, but all positions other than fully closed are presumably not a desired state to be left in when locking up.  So what's needed is a system with a "closed" sensor that gives the opposite behavior of the light from the current one, rather than moving the sensor to detect something like the fully up and open position.

Comment: Driving an LED light directly with the secondary of a transformer - with no diode and no resistor - is not a normal arrangement.  Update your posting with vendor data for the transformer and light.  Depending on that info, you might need nothing more than one diode.

Comment: -1 for unhelpful (to us and to yourself) title.

Answer (score 2):

You should search for an "SPDT reed switch"  These have three terminals: a "common" terminal, one that is connected to the common terminal when the magnet on the door is next to the switch (usually marked "N.O." for normally open), and one that is connected to the common terminal when the magnet on the door is away from the switch (marked "N.C." for normally closed).  You should be able to wire the switch into the existing circuit using the common and NC terminals, though we'd have to see a diagram to be sure.  A warning: reed switches are not made to handle any significant current.

Answer (score 1):

There are really a lot of options here but most of them depends on the characteristics of currently used components. I'll throw a couple of 1st that came to my mind.

1. Get a NC (normally closed) reed switch. And/or 3-pin NC/NO switch. The one that is normally closed means that it will conduct once the external magnet are moved away from it.
2. Add a P-channel MOSFET. Where drain-source would be connected in series with your LED and gate will connect to a reed switch and have a resistor of ~4.7-10K pulling it to ground. When your door are closed, your NO reed switch will conduct and gate-source voltage will be equal means that transistor will be closed and won't conduct on drain-source. Once door are opened, reed will stop to conduct and the pull-down resistor will put the gate at ground voltage which opens the drain-source channel. But the MOSFET characteristics must match your circuit characteristics.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOjehx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>